# What can I use instead of mct (multi-controlled Toffoli)? (Grover's algorithm)

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm, ibm-quantum-devices

I implemented the general diffuser (for arbitrary qubits) in Grover's algorithm in terms of an Multi-controlled Toffoli (MCT) gate (it flips target when all controlled gates are 1). However, this gate is not accepted by the IBM quantum computers (not among the basis gates).

Sorry for my naïve question, but how can I replace a mct gate with something that works on IBM quantum computers?

Edit 1:
Thank you for the answer. I added

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_lima')
custom_basis = backend.configuration().basis_gates
grover = transpile(grover,basis_gates=custom_basis)
```

Now, I can send it to the simulators. But not an actual quantum computer such as ibmq_lima. In https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09976.pdf section IV, they talk about approximating mct gates (still reading and learning). I'm just a hobbyist.

Edit 2:
The solution given by Ohad works, i.e. using  `transpile(grover, backend = backend)` in the code. Many thanks. And indeed, I sent the job (Grover's algorithm to find the solution $|00000\rangle$) to ibmq_lima (5 qubits) and it gave me:
[image]

While a simulator gives the expected results:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details, e.g. definition of MCT gate?

Comment: Use `transpile(grover, backend = backend)` and you will be able to run it on a specific backend. BTW, If you run Grover's algorithm on *ibmq_lima* you'll probably get mostly noise and not valuable results..

Comment: consider writing a follow up question instead of extending this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use qiskit's [transpiler](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.html#transpile).
It *transpiles* a given circuit to an equivalent (in functionality) circuit a given backend can run.
I don't know any quantum computer that natively can run multi-qubit gates - Only single qubit and 2-qubit gates.

Answer (score 0):

The transpilation process takes the backend to adapt the circuit to that target. The following code will work even if `backend` is a simulator:

```
grover = transpile(grover, backend)
job = backend.run(grover)
```